# Creation of block mesh for minecraft like chunk

Tags: lwjgl, minecraft-modding, vbo, mesh

**Problem:**

I'm trying to build a naive mesh for a "chunk" of 2x2x2 blocks. But the "mesh" i create is 3x3x3 blocks (i don't understand why?) and the "extra cubes" are not like i intendet them to be (image at the end).

**My code for creation of the mesh:**

```
/**
 * Creates vertices and indices for a mesh
 * @return
 */
public FloatBuffer createVerticesAsBuffer(){
    vertexPositionData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer((24*3)*worldSize*worldSize*worldSize);
    indicesData = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(worldSize*worldSize*worldSize*36);
    int i = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < worldSize; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < worldSize; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < worldSize; z++) {
                if(world[x][y][z] == BlockType.Grass)
                {
                    i += putVertices(x*cubeSize, y*cubeSize, -z*cubeSize, i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

/**
 * Creates cube data and puts it into buffers for one mesh
 * @param tx
 * @param ty
 * @param tz
 * @param offset number of indices
 * @return number of vertices added
 */
public int putVertices(float tx, float ty, float tz, int offset) {
    vertexPositionData.put(new float[]{           
            // Back face
            -cubeSize + tx,cubeSize + ty,-cubeSize + tz,    //0
            -cubeSize + tx,-cubeSize + ty,-cubeSize + tz,   //1
            cubeSize  + tx,-cubeSize + ty,-cubeSize + tz,   //2
            cubeSize + tx,cubeSize + ty,-cubeSize + tz,     //3

            // Front face
            -cubeSize + tx,cubeSize + ty,cubeSize + tz,     //4
            -cubeSize + tx,-cubeSize + ty,cubeSize + tz,    //5
            cubeSize + tx,-cubeSize + ty,cubeSize + tz,     //6
            cubeSize + tx,cubeSize + ty,cubeSize + tz,      //7

            // Right face
            cubeSize + tx,cubeSize + ty,-cubeSize + tz,     //8
            cubeSize + tx,-cubeSize + ty,-cubeSize + tz,    //9
            cubeSize + tx,-cubeSize + ty,cubeSize + tz,     //10
            cubeSize + tx,cubeSize + ty,cubeSize + tz,      //11

            // Left face
            -cubeSize + tx,cubeSize + ty,-cubeSize + tz,    //12
            -cubeSize + tx,-cubeSize + ty,-cubeSize + tz,   //13
            -cubeSize + tx,-cubeSize + ty,cubeSize + tz,    //14
            -cubeSize + tx,cubeSize + ty,cubeSize + tz,     //15

            // Top face
            -cubeSize + tx,cubeSize + ty,cubeSize + tz,     //16
            -cubeSize + tx,cubeSize + ty,-cubeSize + tz,    //17
            cubeSize + tx,cubeSize + ty,-cubeSize + tz,     //18
            cubeSize + tx,cubeSize + ty,cubeSize + tz,      //19

            // Bottom face
            -cubeSize + tx,-cubeSize + ty,cubeSize + tz,    //20
            -cubeSize + tx,-cubeSize + ty,-cubeSize + tz,   //21
            cubeSize + tx,-cubeSize + ty,-cubeSize + tz,    //22
            cubeSize + tx,-cubeSize + ty,cubeSize + tz      //23
    });
    indicesData.put(new int[]{
            0+offset,1+offset,3+offset, // Back face
            3+offset,1+offset,2+offset, // Back face

            4+offset,5+offset,7+offset, // Front face
            7+offset,5+offset,6+offset, // Front face

            8+offset,9+offset,11+offset, // Right face
            11+offset,9+offset,10+offset, // Right face

            12+offset,13+offset,15+offset, // Left face
            15+offset,13+offset,14+offset, // Left face

            16+offset,17+offset,19+offset, // Top face
            19+offset,17+offset,18+offset, // Top face

            20+offset,21+offset,23+offset, // Bottom face
            23+offset,21+offset,22+offset // Bottom face
    });
    return 24;
}
```

Full code on github: https://github.com/karoc123/ba_tobias_zink/tree/master/LWJGLTest

**My actual output:** [image: output of the vbo created]